# TFS error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.ControlAdapter, Version=12.0.0.0'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, ranorex, msscci, visual-studio-exp-2013

I am using Ranorex 7.2 on Windows 10.

We are using VS 2013 Express Desktop update 4 with the 2013 version of the MSSCCI plugin. When I try and link Ranorex to TFS (which can be done from inside Ranorex), I get the following error popup in Ranorex:
'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.ControlAdapter, Version=12.0.0.0'. As can be seen in the attached screen grab, it points at an invalid pointer. Has anyone had this error appear when trying to link VS & Ranorex, or any other 3rd party app?

I have even tried rolling back to VS 2012 with the 2012 MSCCI and all that changed, was that the 'Version' mentioned in the error went from 12.0.0.0 to 11.0.0.0. I am now back on VS 2013 with the 2013 MSSCCI. Based on a post on the Microsoft forum, I have also installed VS Remote Tools and VS Agents, but this has not fixed the problem.

As far as I'm aware, the company is using TFS 2016, which I would assume is fully patched and updated.

Any clues, pointers and suggestions that anyone has would be most welcome.

Comment: Did you install Team Explorer or the TFS 2013 object model?

Comment: Sorry Daniel, I'm not sure what you mean. I installed VS 2013 Express update 4.

Comment: I don't recall if VS Express contained the TFS object model. I'm guessing it didn't. Try to install the TFS 2013 object model or Team Explorer 2013. You should be able to find them with a simple web search. Your company is defnitely not using TFS 2016, because there is no such thing.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I didn't think TFS 2016 sounded right when the support guy said it :-). The guy who normally looks after it is off this week.

Comment: We have experienced compatibility issues with VS2013 but we use VSTS (TFS2018).  You can check this link for a compatibility table: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/vsts/tfs-server/requirements#client-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Install Team Foundation Server 2013 Object Model Installer from website below:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErinDormierMSFT.TeamFoundationServer2013ObjectModelInstaller

And you could try to install [VS 2013 community version](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/) and [TFS 2013 MSSCCI Provider](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer20132015M) to see whether the issue persists.

Comment: Hi Cece, I have downloaded and installed the object model installer. I have located the dll in the VS folder, but I don't know what you mean by reload it. I have tried relinking Ranorex to TFS, but the 'could not load file or assembly' error is still there.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall VS 2013 with the 2013 MSSCCI?

Comment: Not since I installed the Object Model Installer. I will do it now if you think it will help.

Comment: Hi Cece, Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. Unfortunately my issue still exists. I have had the opportunity to do a clean install of VS 2013 Express release 5, MSSCCI 2013, TFS object Modeller 2013 and Ranorex. Unfortunately the error still happens at the point that Ranorex tries to link with TFS. I am not sure where we go from here. THanks for all your suggestions so far.

Comment: Are you able to find which version of TFS you are using?

Comment: Hi Cece, I have finally found out that our TFS server is 2017. Given the amount of time I've spent trying to resolve it, even with your assistance, we are giving up on TFS and moving to  SVN. Thank you for all your assistance. Regards James.

Comment: There is no MSSCCI Provider for TFS 2017, but Ranorex uses this MSSCCI provider, I'm afraid that's why it doesn't work.